# Uploading an image cropped using a cropper.js plugin in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, laravel-5

I have used cropper.js plugin in my application to crop image. I am able to crop the images. Now I am trying to send the images to server and save them. I have updated the the modal window that shows the cropped image as follows:

```
ent<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Cropper</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img id="image" src="" alt="Picture">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>er code here
```

and i send image to server with Ajax request as following script:

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'upload/image-crop',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('Upload success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Upload error');
                    }
                });
            });
```

and save image in controller as follow:

```
public function uploadImageCrop(Request $request){
    $data = $request->croppedImage;
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $image_name= time().'.jpg';
    $path = public_path() . "\images\upload\img" . $image_name;
    file_put_contents($path, $data);
    return response()->json(['success'=>'done']);
}
```

this work successfully but dont save valid image.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it works successfully'. Do you get the json response `['success'=>'done']`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues may be from trying to upload an image via `GET`. Try changing the HTTP verb to `POST` in your ajax request and `routes.php`

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload/image-crop',
                type: 'POST',
                ...
```